# Extracting dates between a start and end date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark

I have two dates below:
start = `2018-02-15`
end = `2021-02-05`

If I pass these two dates to a method I need to get the output as below.

```
  Start       End
2018-02-15  2018-03-15
2018-03-15  2018-04-15
2018-04-15  2018-05-15
2018-05-15  2018-06-15
...
2021-01-15  2021-02-05
```

Is there a way through I can achieve this in python, Pandas or in spark?

Comment: You're looking for `datetime.timedelta(days=30)`

Comment: @AvenDesta, `datetime.timedelta(days=30)` will not do, because OP wants same date each month and months have different number of days.

Comment: @buran yep, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can explode two sequences of dates:

```
start = '2018-02-15'
end = '2021-02-05'

df = spark.sql(f"""
    select
        explode(
            arrays_zip(
                sequence(date('{start}'), date('{end}') - interval 1 month, interval 1 month),
                sequence(date('{start}') + interval 1 month, date('{end}'), interval 1 month)
           )
       )
""").selectExpr('col.*').toDF('start', 'end')
```

Comment: what language is it?

Comment: @AvenDesta spark sql

Comment: @mck , it is truncating from 2021-01-15 to 2021-02-05

Comment: @mck 
I see below dates
```
|start     |end       |
|2018-02-15|2018-03-15|
|2018-03-15|2018-04-15|
...
|2020-11-15|2020-12-15|
|2020-12-15|2021-01-15|
```
There should be an another entry from 2021-01-15 to 2021-02-05 for the remaining days.